Seasonality in ECM: Controlling Within the Model (e.g., Adding Dummies) vs. Outside the Model (e.g., Seasonal Adjustment)
When running an Error Correction Model (ECM) with seasonal data, two main strategies are typically considered (for example here and here):

Incorporating seasonal dummies within the model to control for seasonality.
Adjusting for seasonality outside the model by decomposition of the seasonal component of each variable.

Is there a consensus in the literature regarding the preferred option? In other words, is it generally better to adjust for seasonal data rather than adding dummies, or are the differences generally small?
Additionally, if one uses seasonal dummies and the two-step Engle–Granger method, should these dummies be included only in the full ECM or also in the long-run regression?
I would appreciate any guidance or references to literature discussing these approaches!
